# Como somar números em sequência no JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando resolver uma questão, mas não consigo. Ela tem uma função que recebe um parâmetro, esse parâmetro tem um número e é basicamente para somar de 1 até o número desse parâmetro em sequência. Como em 1 + 2 + 3 + 4... e retornar o resultado da soma desses números.

Eu estou tentando resolver desta maneira:

```
function somatotal(numero) {
    for (var cont = 0; cont < numero; cont++) {
        var resultado = cont + 1
        return resultado         
    } 
}
```

Mas não está dando.

Answer (score 3):

Basicamente seu algoritmo tem 2 erros:

- Não incrementa o resultado e sim cria um novo valor;
- Retorna dentro do laço de repetição.

Corrigindo esses erros teríamos:

```js
function somatotal(numero) {
  let resultado = 0;

  for (let cont = 1; cont <= numero; cont += 1) {
    resultado += cont;
  }
  
  return resultado;
}

console.log(somatotal(5));
```

Comment: oi, eu arrumei o que você apontou e funcionou, obrigada!

Comment: @MaioAmarelo não esqueça de aceitar a resposta como escolhida caso a resposta tenha lhe ajudado.